# How do I check if there's an array within an array

Tags: javascript

How do I check if there's an array within an array? For example, if I had this array `[5, 65, [5]]` it would return true. In this case, `[6, 12, 54, 3]` it would return false. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) as predicate for checking with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
console.log([5, 65, [5]].some(Array.isArray));   // true
console.log([6, 12, 54, 3].some(Array.isArray)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test it with a function like following:

```
function isArrayWithinArray(arr){
   for (var el in arr) {
     if(arr[el] instanceof Array)
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

See example above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var arrTest1 = [5, 65, [5]];
    var arrTest2 = [6, 12, 54, 3];
    
    function isArrayWithinArray(arr){
      for (var el in arr) {
        if(arr[el] instanceof Array)
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    
    console.log("arrTest1: " + isArrayWithinArray(arrTest1));
    console.log("arrTest2; " + isArrayWithinArray(arrTest2));
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.